# How to make two entries of second table as two columns for a select query from first table?

Tags: mysql

I want two display the result of the second table 'e_value', wich are two records (from only one column), as two columns for the select query from first table 'e_order_item'.
Also I am displaying many order items using a parameter 'collect_id', 
so I want to display each two values of the table 'e_value' using to the order item id displayed on the select query.

for example, I have this on the tables

```
+-------------------------------+
|         e_order_item          |
+-------------------------------+
| oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id |
| 1         100         2       |
| 2         30          2       |
| 3         55          3       |
| 4         70          4       |
| 5         220         2       |
| 6         300         2       |
+-------------------------------+

+----------------------------+
|          e_value           |
+----------------------------+
| v_id   v_value     v_oi_id |
| 1        name1         1   |
| 2        surname1      1   |
| 3        name2         2   |
| 4        surname2      2   |
| 5        name3         5   |
| 6        surname3      5   |
+----------------------------+
```

I want to select the order_items that have collect_id = 2, and I want the result to be like this

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                Result                            |
| oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id   name    surname  |
| 1         100         2         name1   surname1 |
| 2         30          2         name2   surname2 |
| 5         220         2         name3   surname3 |
| 6         300         2         null    null     |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Hint: `LEFT JOIN` & `Pivoting (Case when)`

Comment: @user2285831 I have given you the solution please check it whether it satisfies you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    t.oi_id,
    t.oi_price,
    t.oi_collect_id,
    LEFT (
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value),
        IF (
                LOCATE(',',GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)) = 0,
                LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)),
                LOCATE(',', GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)) - 1
            )
    ) 'Name',
    RIGHT (
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value),
        LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)) -
    IF (
            LOCATE(',',GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)) = 0,
            LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value)),
            LOCATE(',',GROUP_CONCAT(t.v_value))
        )
    ) Surname
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM e_order_item
        LEFT JOIN e_value ON e_order_item.oi_id = e_value.v_oi_id
        WHERE   e_order_item.oi_collect_id = 2
        ORDER BY    oi_id, v_id
    ) t
GROUP BY t.oi_id;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0aa2/3/0)

**Note:**

The following example illustrates how we can get the first string and second string from a comma separated string.

```
SET @str := 'A,BCDEFGHIJKL';
SELECT 
LEFT(@str,IF(LOCATE(',',@str) = 0, LENGTH(@str),LOCATE(',',@str)-1)) AS StringBeforeComma,
RIGHT(@str,LENGTH(@str)-IF(LOCATE(',',@str)=0,LENGTH(@str),LOCATE(',',@str))) AS StringAfterComma
```

**Result:**

```
StringBeforeComma      StringAfterComma

    A                    BCDEFGHIJKL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for pivoting to get the desired result.

```
select oi_id, oi_price, oi_collect_id
     , max(name) as name
     , max(surname) as surname
  from (
    select
           i.oi_id, i.oi_price, i.oi_collect_id
         , case when @prevVal <> (@currVal:=v.v_oi_id)
                     then v.v_value
                else null
            end as name
         , case when @prevVal = @currVal
                     then v.v_value
                else null
            end as surname
         , @prevVal:=@currVal as temp_currVal
      from e_order_item i
      left join e_value v on v.v_oi_id = i.oi_id,
      (select @prevVal:=-1, @currVal:=-1) as inits
     where i.oi_collect_id=2
) as main_data
 group by oi_id, oi_price, oi_collect_id
 order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and run successfully...and give output as you want...
There are two subqueries:
1.First will give all result having `collect_id = 2`...

```
1.SELECT tab1.oi_id, tab1.oi_price, tab1.oi_collect_id
 from(
    SELECT oi_id, oi_price, oi_collect_id
    from e_order_item
    where oi_collect_id = 2
 ) as tab1;
```

2.This query will give you name, surname and id in different columns..

```
2.(SELECT e.v_value as name, surname, id
   from (
       select t1.v_value as surname, t1.v_oi_id as id from e_value as t1
       group by t1.v_oi_id
    )join  e_value as e on id = e.v_oi_id and surname <> e.v_value
) as tab2 on tab1.oi_id = tab2.id;
```

Now `left join` these two query to get our desired result as:

```
SELECT tab1.oi_id, tab1.oi_price, tab1.oi_collect_id, name, surname
from(
    SELECT oi_id, oi_price, oi_collect_id
    from e_order_item
    where oi_collect_id = 2
) as tab1 left join 

(SELECT e.v_value as name, surname, id
    from (
        select t1.v_value as surname, t1.v_oi_id as id from e_value as t1
        group by t1.v_oi_id
    )join  e_value as e on id = e.v_oi_id and surname <> e.v_value

) as tab2 on tab1.oi_id = tab2.id

order by tab1.oi_id asc;   // to print in ascending order..
```

Why we use `left join`..You can use this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp to understand properly...
If this solution is helpful then let me know...